# Moving average of a signal

Tags: filters, discrete-signals, moving-average

Problem is to find 1 second moving average of a signal having sample time as Ts.

To solve this, it is suggested to pass the signal through a Butterworth low pass filter having the following specifications:

Cutoff frequency = $\cfrac{1}{2\pi\times0.5} \texttt{Hz}$

Can you please suggest how one second moving average is equivalent to the Butterworth low pass filter with the above cutoff frequency

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can you please suggest how one second moving average is equivalent to the Butterworth low pass filter with the above cutoff frequency

It's not. Full stop!

It is, however, also a low-pass filter, and thus has an *averaging effect*. However, if you're asked to design a moving average, you're not asked to design a Butterworth filter.

> Cutoff frequency $= 1/(2\pi\cdot0.5)$ Hz

What they do here is say "here, look, a unit-length moving average filter has a (frequency) amplitude response, which has a zero at $f=1/\pi$. We just arbitrarily declare the Butteworth filter with a cutoff at that point to be equivalent!"

But that's, frankly speaking, nonsense. The cutoff frequency for a Butterworth filter is the point its amplitude response drops below -3 dB, not the point where it reaches 0, or after which it increases again.

So, I can't really see any case where I'd want to implement a moving average filter as a Butterworth filter, **especially** not for a sampled signal, where building a Butterworth filter is hard, but a moving average is very easy.

So, whoever recommended that had some other constraints in mind that they're not telling you here. It *is **not** generally suggested* to do what you are being suggested to do.

Comment: Got your point, but my doubt here is; why specifically 1/pi, why not 2/pi or 3/pi, on what basis is time constant selected as 0.5

Comment: I addressed that in my answer! It's where the sinc spectral shape of the moving average has  a zero, but it makes no sense to use it as cutoff frequency. I'm sorry that I can't make the recommendation you've been given make any more sense: it's just not a very good or useful recommendation.